# How would you say, "why don't you come over?"

Tags: translation

I may be wrong but would 「そちらに来ない？」translate as "Do you want to come over?" And does the Japanese language even use the word 「そちら」in that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そちら means in the direction opposite the speaker but near the intended listener. Your phrasing is equivalent to saying something inconsistent like 'Come there'.

You want to use こちら, as that would indicate the location where you are at.

The word for 'want to' is missing from your Japanese example. As in English we use the expression 'Do you wanna come over' as an invitation rather than a question as to that person's desire to do so, what you really want to translate is 'Won't you come here?', for which 「こちらに来ない？」would be appropriate in a casual/friendly relationship.

Answer (score -2):

Among close friends we will say ( kimasuka ):

> 来ますか

or

( kuruka )

> 来るか

( kurukai - adding the い on the end converts it to an even more informal question and implies or questions as a desire - comin' over?  or wanna come over? )

> 来るかい

( kuro nano - won't you come over )

> 来るなの

( or just kuru? )

> 来る?

( you won't find any of these in books and translator apps will have difficulty with them as well )

北海道ベンだ

Comment: 「来るなの」 is not grammatical.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Adding "na no" to the end of a sentence as a question is a colloquialism from the most northern island of Hokkaido, "Hokkaidoben" ( Sapporo area ) that is used quite commonly among close friends and family ( low level usage ) especially with teenagers and kids and college age.  It is used more commonly than "ka" at the end for a question up there.